# Test of integers? Or, round the number if the first two decimal numbers are sufficiently close to 0 or 1?

Tags: tables, tikzmath, decimal-number

The following is a MWE, which explains my intention.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
\integer = 4/2; \decimal = 5/3; 
\integerB=1/3*3;
}
$\integer$ is an integer, and it should be printed as 2. 
And $\decimal$ is a decimal number, I would like to round it to 1.7. 
Another difficulty is that $\integerB$  is an integer in fact, 
and should be printed as 1. 
\end{document}
```

I wonder if it is possible to test a number to determine it is an integer. Alternatively, it would also be great if it is possible to determine whether the first two decimal numbers are sufficiently close to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}% recommended package

\newcommand\test[1]{\xintifboolexpr{ifint(#1, 1, 0)}
  {\xinttheexpr reduce(#1)\relax\space (originally \texttt{\detokenize{#1}})
   is an integer.}
  {\xinttheiexpr[2] #1\relax\space (originally \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}), 
   we rounded to two decimal places) is not an integer.}\par
}

\begin{document}

\test{4/2}

\test{5/3}

\test{(1/3)*3}

\test{(1/7 - 1/8 - 1/57)*3192}

\test{(1/2 - 1/3 - 1/7 - 1/43 - 1/1807 - 1/3263443)*10650056950806}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: strangely xintexpr has `ifint(expression, YES, NO)` function but not `isint(expression)` which would evaluate to 1 or 0 directly.

Comment: about "Alternatively, it would also be great if it is possible to determine whether the first two decimal numbers are sufficiently close to 0 or 1." this can be done by xintexpr of course as it computes exactly with arbitrarily big fractions. But I don't know exactly what is asked here.

Comment: for comparison `\fpeval{(1/2 - 1/3 - 1/7 - 1/43 - 1/1807 - 1/3263443)*10650056950806}` evaluates to `0.9999211586333241`,  exactly like `\xintthefloatexpr...\relax`. But the latter after `\xintDigits:=48;` will evaluate to `1.00000000000000000000000000000000000522205263811`.

Comment: FWIW, using the default precision settings, Lua evaluates `(1/2 - 1/3 - 1/7 - 1/43 - 1/1807 - 1/3263443)*10650056950806` as `1.000285363444`. Of course, `\round{\comp{(1/2 - 1/3 - 1/7 - 1/43 - 1/1807 - 1/3263443)*10650056950806}}{1}` (where `\round` and `\comp` are defined in my answer) produces `1`. Whew!

Answer (score 6):

One cannot say from its floating point representation whether the output of an arithmetic operation involving division or non rational operations is actually an integer.

You can consider the `l3fp` module of `expl3`, available through the package `xfp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

$\fpeval{5/3}$ is a decimal number, I would like to round it to
$\fpeval{round(5/3,1)}$ or to $\fpeval{round(5/3,2)}$

Another difficulty is that $\fpeval{(1/3)*3}$ is an integer in fact, 
and should be printed as $\fpeval{round((1/3)*3,1)}$ or
$\fpeval{round((1/3)*3,2)}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the accuracy of your numbers is important you might consider farming that out to a computer algebra system (CAS). The `sagetex` package relies on the CAS Sage; the documentation can be found on CTAN right [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). Documentation on Sage is found [here](http://www.sagemath.org/) .Sage is not part of the LaTeX distribution (it's big) so it needs to be installed on your computer or, even easier, accessed through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
a = 4/2
b = 5/3
c = 1/3*3
\end{sagesilent}
$\sage{a}$ is an integer, and it should be printed as     $\sage{a}$. 
And $\sage{b}$ is not an integer. As a decimal it is     approximately
$\sage{b.n(digits=6)}$. I would like to round it to     $\sage{b.n(digits=1)}$. 
Another difficulty is that $\sage{c}$ is an integer in fact, 
and should be printed as $\sage{c}$. 
\end{document}
```

The output, running in Cocalc, gives:
[image]

Notice that Sage interprets your numbers correctly: 4/2 is recognized as 2 and 1/3*3 is recognized as 1. It does need to know the format you want of non integers; but it recognizes that 5/3 is a fraction that can't be reduced and leaves it as a fraction. To force it into a decimal and to specify the number of digits we append .n(digits=6); the documentation is [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/functional.html).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is a question on how to do this with tikzmath, I'd do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
function myint(\x) {
    if abs(\x-round(\x)) < 0.1 then { print{\x\ is an integer\newline};
      return int(round(\x));
    } else { print{\x\ is not an integer\newline};
       return \x;
}; };
\integer = myint(4/2); 
\decimal = myint(5/3);
\integerB= myint(1/3*3);
}


$\integer$ is an integer, and it should be printed as 2. 
And $\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\decimal}$ is a decimal number, I would like to round it to 1.7. 
Another difficulty is that $\integerB$  is an integer in fact, 
and should be printed as 1. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I used `\pgfmathprintnumber` to round to one digit after the dot. Of course, you can remove the `print`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. `\integer` (4/2) and `\integerB` ((1/3)*3) evaluate to integers automatically according to Lua rules. The LaTeX macro `\round`, which takes two arguments, lets users round numbers to a specified set of digits after the decimal marker.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
% Set up 2 auxilliary Lua functions to round numbers
\directlua{
function math.round_int ( x )
   return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
end
function math.round ( x , n )
  return ( math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n )
end
}
\newcommand\comp[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}
\newcommand\round[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.round(#1,#2))}}

\newcommand{\integer}{\comp{4/2}}
\newcommand{\decimal}{\comp{5/3}} 
\newcommand{\integerB}{\comp{(1/3)*3}}

\begin{document}
\integer\ is an integer. 

\integerB\ is also an integer. 

\decimal\ is a decimal number. I would like to round it to \round{\decimal}{1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: does `(1/7-1/8-1/57)*3192` evaluate to an integer in Lua? (just curious...)

Comment: in case answer is yes (perhaps from some distributivity done automatically), I have `(1/7 - 1/8 - 1/57)*(3000+192)` up my sleeve :)

Comment: @jfbu - Both expressions evaluate to `0.99999999999998` (13 nines followed by an 8), using the standard number of significant digits used in `tex.sprint`. If I reduced that number by 1 or 2 digits, one is back to `1` (pun intended).

Comment: I think `\xintthefloatexpr` works with `\xintDigits:=2;` but I am not sure with only 1 digit :) you are really quite a challenge!