# Calculating with \directlua in Plain LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, calculations, lua

I have never used Lua before, so I have some questions about the calculations:

1. How can avoid appending `.0` if the result is an integer?
2. How can I achieve that the right number of zeros is appended after rounding?
3. How can I change the decimal marker `.` into a comma `,`?

What I have tried (MWE):

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\catcode`\@=11

% From latex.ltx
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
    \let\reserved@d=#1%
    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
    \def\reserved@b{#3}%
    \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
\def\@ifnch{%
    \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \let\reserved@c\@xifnch
    \else
    \ifx\@let@token\reserved@d
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
    \else
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
    \fi
    \fi
    \reserved@c}
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \:  % this makes \@sptoken a space token
\def\:{\@xifnch} \expandafter\def\: {\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}

% seen somewhere on tex.stackexchange.com
\directlua{
function math.round_int ( x )
  return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
end
function math.round ( x , n )
  return ( math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n )
end
}

% My macros
\def\c@lc[#1]#2{\directlua{tex.print(math.round(#2,#1))}}
\def\calc{\@ifnextchar[\c@lc{\c@lc[2]}} % Default is rounding to 10^-2

Let's try the macros:

$ \sqrt2 \approx \calc[4]{2^(1/2)} $ is OK.

$ \root5\of{32} = \calc{32^(1/5)} $ should be $2$ as it is an integer.

$ 1.699999 \approx \calc[3]{1.699999} $ should be $1.700$ because it is rounded to $10^{-3}$.

$ 1.9 \approx \calc[0]{1.9} $ should be $2$ as it is rounded to whole numbers.

$ 8 \approx \calc[-1]{8} $ should be $10$ as it is rounded to $10^1$.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: LuaTeX *always* adds a digit after the decimal point (even if it's 0) when a calculation involves operations on floating point numbers, which `32^(1/5)` is, for instance.

Comment: This is due to the way Lua 5.3 is handling its numbers. To avoid the decimal point, you should use one of the proper string format: '%d' should make it as far as I understand. Hans Hagen gave an example in the last ConTeXt group proceedings: `local b=2*(1/2) print(string.format("%d", b), math.type(x))` gives as output `b 2*(1/2) d 1 float`

Comment: @sztruks - Your brief comments were actually helpful to me as I began thinking about a solution. :-) For the issue at hand, though, it's better to apply coercion-to-int *if* the value of the rounding operation is known to be integer-valued (which will be the case if `n` is 0 or negative). If `n` is positive, then a `string.format ( "%."..n.."f" , <rounded number here>)` operation is probably most appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You asked,

> How can I avoid appending `.0` if the result [of the rounding operation] is an integer?

In the versions of Lua prior to 5.3, there was only a single numeric data type ("float"); however, Lua was programmed to display numbers *without* decimal parts without the trailing `.0`, i.e., as though they were whole numbers (which, of course, they are). Version 5.3 of Lua introduced a new numeric data type called "integer"; Lua version 5.3 was incorporated into LuaTeX earlier this year (2019). A side effect of this change is that whole numbers are now shown without a trailing `.0` only if their *type* is "integer". (Of course, Lua 5.3 provides methods for converting a number from type `float` to type `integer`. One of these methods is employed in the code shown below.)

The issue you're experiencing, then, is caused by the fact that the Lua function `math.round`, which is called by `\c@lc`, always returns a number of type "float"; hence the trailing `.0`. To display whole numbers without a trailing `.0`, I suggest you make two changes. First, add the following code chunk

```
function math.myround ( x , n )
  if n==0 then
    return ( math.round_int ( x ) )
  elseif n<0 then
    return ( math.floor ( math.round ( x , n ) ) )
  else 
    return ( math.round ( x , n ) )
  end
end
```

to the argument of the first `\directlua` call. Second change

```
\def\c@lc[#1]#2{\directlua{tex.print(math.round(#2,#1))}}
```

to

```
\def\c@lc[#1]#2{\directlua{tex.print(math.myround(#2,#1))}}
```

How does `math.myround` differ from `math.round`? The function `math.myround` calls `math.round_int` directly if the first argument of `\c@lc` is 0, i.e., if rounding to the nearest integer is to be performed. Moreover, it applies coercion-from-float-to-integer (after calling `math.round`) if the first argument of `\c@lc` is negative. That way, the rounded number returned by `math.myround` is of *type* `integer` if `n` is 0 or negative, i.e., if the rounded number is, in fact, an whole number.

---

You also asked,

> How can I achieve that the right number of zeros is appended after rounding?

If `x` is equal to, say, `1.7` after rounding to `n` digits after the decimal marker (where `n` is an integer, aka a positive whole number), then running

```
string.format ( "%."..n.."f" , x )
```

creates a string with `n` explicit digits after the decimal marker -- some of which may be zero.

*Note:* Since there's a `%` symbol present in the first argument of `string.format`, you can't load the code via `\directlua` as TeX will choke fatally on the `%` symbol. You'll have to place the Lua code into an external file called, say, `myround.lua`, and load that file via the instruction `\directlua{dofile("myround.lua")}`.

---

The third question you asked was,

> How can I change the decimal marker `.` into a comma `,`?

Lua provides a very powerful function called `string.gsub`. (The `g` in `gsub` stands for "global".) You could change

```
    return ( math.round ( x , n ) )
```

in the function `math.myround` to

```
    return ( ( string.gsub ( math.round ( x , n ) , "%." , "{,}" ) )
```

Observe that `.` is changed not to `,` but to `{,}`; this is done to inform TeX that it shouldn't treat these instances of `,` as characters of type `math-punct`.

*Same note as above:* Since there's a `%` symbol present in the argument of `string.gsub`, you mustn't load the code via `\directlua` (since TeX will again choke painfully and agonizingly on the `%` symbol). I suggest you store the Lua code in an external file called, say, `myround.lua`, and load that file via the instruction `\directlua{dofile("myround.lua")}`.

---

The following solution addresses all three questions you asked. It employs LaTeX rather than Plain-TeX, mostly because I don't know how to employ the `filecontents` environment -- which is very useful for creating external files -- in a Plain-TeX setting. See further below, though, for instructions that lead to a Plain-TeX solution.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

 % The next instruction requires LaTeX format 2019-10-01 (or more recent)
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myround.lua}
```

```lua
-- First two functions seen somewhere on tex.stackexchange.com.
-- (Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468118/5001 ??)

function math.round_int ( x )
   return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
end

function math.round ( x , n )
   return math.round_int ( x*10^n ) / 10^n 
end

-- New:
function math.myround ( x , n )
   if n==0 then
      return math.round_int ( x )
   elseif n<0 then
      return math.floor ( math.round ( x , n ) )
   else   -- n>0
      x = math.round ( x , n ) -- replace 'x' with rounded version
      x = string.format ( "%."..n.."f" , x )
      return ( x:gsub ( "%." , "{,}" , 1 ) )
   end
end
```

```tex
\end{filecontents*}

\directlua{dofile("myround.lua")} % Load the externally-stored code

\newcommand\calc[2][0]{% default value of opt. param.: 0
   \directlua{tex.sprint(math.myround(#2,#1))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
Let's try the macros:
$ \sqrt{2} \approx \calc[4]{2^(1/2)} $. OK.
$ \sqrt[5]{32} = \calc{32^(1/5)} $. OK.
$ 1.699999 \approx \calc[3]{1.699999} $. OK.
$ 1.699999 \approx \calc[1]{1.699999} $. Also OK.
$ 1.9 \approx \calc{1.9} $. OK.
$ 8 \approx \calc[-1]{8} $. OK.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: For the sake of completeness, here's how a Plain-TeX solution would look like:

- First, create an external file called `myround.lua` and place in it the contents of the `filecontents` environment (3 Lua functions) shown above.
- Second, delete the contents of the first `\directlua` instruction in your example code, since that code is now contained in the external file.
- Third, replace

  ```
  % My macros
  \def\c@lc[#1]#2{\directlua{tex.print(math.round(#2,#1))}}
  \def\calc{\@ifnextchar[\c@lc{\c@lc[2]}} % Default is rounding to 10^-2
  ```

  with

  ```
  \directlua{dofile("myround.lua")} % load the externally-stored code

  % My macros
  \def\c@lc[#1]#2{\directlua{tex.print(math.myround(#2,#1))}}
  \def\calc{\@ifnextchar[\c@lc{\c@lc[0]}} % Default rounding: to nearest integer
  ```